# Dynamic datatable creation with loop R

Tags: r, loops, datatable

I have the following code:

```
#code
country <- c("AT","AT","AT","BE","BE","BE","CY","CY","CY")
date_yq <- as.yearqtr(c("2015-01-01","2016-03-01","2017-04-06","2015-01-01","2016-03-01","2017-04- 
06","2015-01-01","2016-03-01","2017-04-06"))
var1 <- runif(9)
var2 <- runif(9)
var3 <- runif(9)
var4 <- runif(9)

#remove some obs
var1[1] <- NA
var1[c(4,5)] <- NA
var2[7] <- NA
var3[c(1,2,4)] <- NA
var4[c(4,9)] <- NA

df <- data.table(country, date_yq, var1, var2, var3, var4)
df

df_dates <- df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  summarize(
    var1_min_date = min(date_yq[!is.na(var1)]),
    var1_max_date = max(date_yq[!is.na(var1)]),
    var2_min_date = min(date_yq[!is.na(var2)]),
    var2_max_date = max(date_yq[!is.na(var2)])
    # and so on for var3 and var4
    )

df_dates

#within a loop. Not working

namesvar <- names(df)[-c(1:2)]
for (Nn in namesvar) {

  df2_dates <- df %>% 
    group_by(country) %>% 
    summarize(
      assign(paste0(Nn,"_min_date"), min(date_yq[!is.na(Nn)])),
      assign(paste0(Nn,"_max_date"), max(date_yq[!is.na(Nn)])))

}
```

I would like to create df_dates within a loop since I have a dynamic data table (different number of vars depending on other specifications). Anyone able to help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop, you can `summarize_at` all columns whose names contain `'var'` and apply two anonymous functions to each

```
df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(contains('var')), 
               list(~ min(date_yq[!is.na(.)]), ~ max(date_yq[!is.na(.)])))
# # A tibble: 3 x 9
#   country var1_min  var2_min  var3_min var4_min var1_max var2_max var3_max var4_max
#   <chr>   <yearqtr> <yearqtr> <yearqt> <yearqt> <yearqt> <yearqt> <yearqt> <yearqt>
# 1 AT      2016 Q3   2015 Q1   2017 Q4  2015 Q1  2017 Q4  2017 Q4  2017 Q4  2017 Q4 
# 2 BE      2017 Q4   2015 Q1   2016 Q3  2016 Q3  2017 Q4  2017 Q4  2017 Q4  2017 Q4 
# 3 CY      2015 Q1   2015 Q1   2015 Q1  2015 Q1  2017 Q4  2017 Q4  2017 Q4  2016 Q3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, In the real dataset all variables have different names.

Comment: In that case, replace `vars(contains('var'))` with `-c(1:2)` or your own custom `namesvar` vector.